# Raspberry makefile

Tags: c, makefile, raspberry-pi

I am trying to move a program from my cloud9-ide to my raspberry. But when I move them the makefile no longer works.

```
#
# Makefile
#
# Computer Science 50
# Problem Set 5
#


# compiler to use
CC = clang

# flags to pass compiler
CFLAGS = -ggdb3 -O0 -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror

# name for executable
EXE = myTest

# space-separated list of header files
HDRS = i2cContinuousRead.h

# space-separated list of libraries, if any,
# each of which should be prefixed with -l
LIBS =

# space-separated list of source files
SRCS = myTest.c i2cContinuousRead.c

# automatically generated list of object files
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)


# default target
$(EXE): $(OBJS) $(HDRS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS)

# dependencies 
$(OBJS): $(HDRS) Makefile

# housekeeping
clean:
    rm -f core $(EXE) *.o
```

I get the error output

```
clang -ggdb3  -Qunused-arguments -std=c11 -Wall -Werror   -c -o myTest.o myTest.c
make: clang: Command not found
<builtin>: recipe for target 'myTest.o' failed
make: *** [myTest.o] Error 127
```

I tried to update sudo apt-get install build-essential

I have a fresh install if jessy.

Any tips?

Comment: Maybe you want `CC = gcc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you're compiling with clang, but letting CC = gcc in makefile let you compile your application with gcc, but if you really need clang, you can install it with

> sudo apt-get install clang llvm

Comment: I tried gcc from start but it failed.

So I only assumed i had to use clang. The problem was i had to modify the makefile for gcc flags. (facepalm).

I tried again now and it worked fine.

Thanks and merry x-mas

Answer (score 3):

It seems you haven't installed clang on your system. You can install it as suggested by e.jahandar or use the standard gcc compiler shipped with the linux distro jessy.